# use chart.js on a page that was loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I have gotten a line chart to work on a regular page.  I have another page where I am using the same code, except the page is called via ajax.  The chart is not appearing on the page that is called by ajax.  Here is my code:

```
<div style="width:30%">
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            }
        ]

    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
</script>
```

How do I get the chart to appear on a page loaded by ajax?

Comment: Listen to the `jqXHR.done` event of your AJAX call and then initialize the plugin?

Comment: I've tried wrapping the chart instantiation in '$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){' but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You DOM may not be ready as soon as your AJAX has completed. Try wrapping the Chart initialization in something that checks if the DOM is ready, like so

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, 100)
```

Also, you might want to ensure that your ajaxComplete function is actually getting called.